# How to grab username from the PHP Login Project

Tags: php, image, file-upload, authentication, upload

Okay, so there is going to be a bit of explaining to do.. So, let's start off with what I am trying to achieve here. I am attempting to create an avatar feature for users to upload an image to use for their profile. Here's my concept;

> User Uploads image to directory = Image is renamed according to their username =
>
> When a user visits his profile the image is called by grabbing his username =
>
> So essentially, the image output will look like this `<img src="avatars/$username.png" />`

Now, since I have not had a lot of experience with PHP, I decided to use a pre-built PHP Login Script named "The PHP Login-Project". It makes things quicker.

Here's my dilemma though, I do not know how to access the user name information to use in my upload image php file (this file is named `upload.php`.) So, currently, upload.php allows the user to upload an image, and then renames it with a random bunch of numbers, I do not want this. Instead, in place of the numbers would be the users username. Here's the upload.php file;

```
<?php
$rand = rand(10000000, 999999999);
$file_name = $rand.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$target_dir = "avatars/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        header('Location: http://1.testing.uk.to/PROJECT_SPACE/edit.php');
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

And here's the GitHub Page of the PHP Login-Project: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced).

Now, this question might not be easy to understand if you haven't used/seen the PHP Login-Project. So if you have seen it and know how it works, here's the question I am asking, how can I grab the username of the user and add it into my upload.php file, renaming the uploaded file to match that of the username? Experienced PHP Developers may also understand the question, although looking at the code of PHP Login-Project is advised. Hopefully I have explained what I want in a manner that can help me resolve my issue. Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this function in the Login.php line no.738

```
<code>
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->user_name;
    }
</code>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but, where would I implement this into my upload.php file?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand.. Could you elaborate? Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: $objLogin = new Login(); $userName = $objLogin->getUsername(); in the $userName you will get the logged in user name and you can use this value to update the uploaded file name in upload.php

Comment: Where would I place this code within my upload.php file? (I don't know much about PHP, so sorry for all the questions.)

Comment: before the $file_name = $rand.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]; add the two line which is in previous comment. modify the line as name $file_name = $userName. $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

Comment: Okay, thanks! Just one problem left, the image adds the original file name after the user name, so, for example, if I upload a file called "steve.png" and my username is Testing, the image is renamed to "testingsteve.png", how would I remove the original file name? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Replace the $file_name = $rand.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]; with  $file = explode('.', $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$file_name = $userName.$file[1];

Comment: Okay thanks! Minor problem now (It's the last thing! I promise!), when the image get's uploaded, the file type doesn't get added correctly, instead it shows up as `filenamejpg` where it should have the dot `filename.jpg`.

Comment: Oh sorry! update this line and check $file_name = $userName.'.'.$file[1];

Comment: Perfect! Hey, if you don't mind, would it be possible to chat about something? It will only take 2 seconds, it would be pointless in me asking another question on here! I'll start a discussion in chat, feel free to respond if you'd like :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70461/discussion-between-mynameisnotsocool-and-karthik-n).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the files , the login function is storing the username ins the session. So you can call this session in the above file and use it to assign to variable "$filename".

Comment: Okay so I've added the session in, but I get the error `Undefined variable: _SESSION`. I assume this is because I haven't included a certain file? Therefore the session is undefined? If so, how would I fix this?

Comment: Please check for following point, 1:- Session is started on the page that ur using. 2:- Proper session variable is used. 3: Its not overridden by any other session on some other page.

Comment: Adding `session_start();` to the file makes the error go away, but the files do not get uploaded.